Conda is executed as a bash script when submitted via PBS
I am not able to make a minimal reproducible example because this error comes up from submitting to a server via the PBS job manager.
qsub -N $JOBNAME -S /bin/bash -j y -o ~/Projects/JOBS/$JOBNAME.out << EOF
#!/bin/bash
echo "/////////////////////////////////////"

# Initialize conda for bash

source ~/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh

# Check if conda is activated correctly
which python
which conda
conda list

echo "/////////////////////////////////////"
EOF

After submission, the log file indicates that conda is executed in bash, not python
alexmarc@lome /S/a/t/JOBS> cat reinventTest.out                                                (reinvent4) 
/////////////////////////////////////
/bin/python
~/tools/anaconda3/condabin/conda
~/tools/anaconda3/bin/conda: line 3: import: command not found
~/tools/anaconda3/bin/conda: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `sys.argv'
~/tools/anaconda3/bin/conda: line 6: `if len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1].startswith('shell.') and sys.path and sys.path[0] == '':'
/////////////////////////////////////

Executing the analogous commands in my shell:
alexmarc@lome /S/a/t/P/r/fromDost> which python ; which conda                               (base) 
~/tools/anaconda3/bin/python
~/tools/anaconda3/bin/conda
alexmarc@lome /S/a/t/P/r/fromDost>      

I can find conda, but not my base python executable. I suspect that my python installation doesn't work on the server. The shebang line in the conda executable contains the path to the conda base environment (See EDIT 2). My intuition is that conda executes using my $SHELL because it cannot use said base python executable.
Because I've never observed a python script automatically execute as a bash script when the shebang line pointed to some python interpreter, I thought I'd post here to see if someone could identify what is causing this behavior.
EDIT: I checked my $PATH in the cluster I submitted, at the beginning of my job, and at the end of my job. The $PATH does not change in any of those circumstances
I also see that my conda executable is being set correctly:
+ source ~/tools/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
++ export CONDA_EXE=~/tools/anaconda3/bin/conda
++ CONDA_EXE=~/tools/anaconda3/bin/conda

And the python executable is also being set:
++ CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=~/tools/anaconda3/bin/python

Checking the python version again using the approach suggested by @Charles Duffy
+ which python
/bin/python
+ type python
python is /bin/python

Spooky...
I've posted the full output after setting set -x below
+ which python
/bin/python
+ type python
python is /bin/python
+ command -v python
/bin/python
+ type python3
python3 is /bin/python3
+ command -v python3
/bin/python3
+ which conda
~/tools/anaconda3/condabin/conda
+ conda list
+ local cmd=list
+ case "$cmd" in
+ __conda_exe list
+ ~/tools/anaconda3/bin/conda list
~/tools/anaconda3/bin/conda: line 3: import: command not found
~/tools/anaconda3/bin/conda: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `sys.argv'
~/tools/anaconda3/bin/conda: line 6: `if len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1].startswith('shell.') and sys.path and sys.path[0] == '':'

EDIT 2:
Here is my conda executable's head as per Ljm Dullaart's request
alexmarc@lome ~/JOBS> head ~/tools/anaconda3/bin/conda              (base) 
#!~/tools/anaconda3/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
# Before any more imports, leave cwd out of sys.path for internal 'conda shell.*' commands.
# see https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6549
if len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1].startswith('shell.') and sys.path and sys.path[0] == '':
    # The standard first entry in sys.path is an empty string,
    # and os.path.abspath('') expands to os.getcwd().
    del sys.path[0]


sourcing the conda.sh script defines a conda shell function. which doesn't know anything about functions, so its output is simply wrong when they're in play -- use type python or command -v python instead of which python, and use set -x to trace execution.

As you will see in my edits based on your advice, conda is running a routine to set my python executable, but that does not match the output of type python or command -v python. This looks like a bug to me. Conda should provide some error or warning to indicate the change in python executables is not reflected in my $SHELL

Have you verified that the directory where your conda is installed is actually mounted on the compute nodes? Also your submission command suggests that this is PBS rather than Slurm.

Add typeset -F to your script, just after the last which. Also, do a head ~/tools/anaconda3/bin/conda

@Nox You are right. I changed the title and tags to reflect the job manager. I can cd into the directory containing my python interpreter, which is inside my conda installation, so it looks like the appropriate directory is mounted

@LjmDullaart I've checked that (see EDIT 2), the shebang line is what you'd expect.

I think my sysadmin has properly diagnosed the issue. Thanks @CharlesDuffy for teaching me a useful new command (set -x), and to everyone here who considered my problem.

I've chatted with my sysadmin, who tells me I would need a Python interpreter which was compiled for the cluster's specific system architecture.
I used
uname -a

Which revealed the system architecture. I'd rather not post the output here, but the important bit is that the server on which I was attempting to use my conda environment is aarch64, the architecture on which I use my conda environment is x86_64.
I'm left to assume the default behavior for at least this particular server is to ignore the shebang line if the interpreter is incompatible with the architecture.

That's a shell behavior more than a behavior of the server as a whole -- if execve fails on a file with +x, some shells will try to interpret that file as a script. You wouldn't see that behavior if, by contrast, you tried to start the same executable from Python's subprocess.Popen() with shell=False, or anything else that just does an execve with no fallback.

Thanks for sharing. The sever's default was tcsh, but I submitted the script in bash.
